# Why does can't heroku find the gdal204.dll file on app deployment?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, geodjango

I am deploying a django postgres sql app on heroku. Everything is working correctly on my machine(windows 10). However whenever I try to deploy to heroku it says it can't locate the gdal204.dll file.

This is how I am currently referencing the gdal file in my app settings:

`GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\IFY\\Downloads\\publish\\Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo\\gdal204.dll'`

I suspect that the way I'm referencing the file is what's causing the issue.

Here is the error that heroku returns on deployment:

`OSError: C:\Users\IFY\Downloads\publish\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal204.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku is not running windows on their servers, but Linux. So there will be no DLL files.

In the python-buildpack Heroku [installs GDAL for you](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/gdal), so you don't have to do it. Furthermore, the corresponding environment variables (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) are set so your app can find the library.

TLDR: for Heroku you should *not* set `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH`  in your settings, and let python find the shared library on it's own. It will work.

Comment: I did that and redeployed the app. Now I'm getting this error: ```Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?```

Comment: @Osaro this is an unrelated error, check if you have django in your requirement.txt or pipfile

Comment: Yes it's there. It was working fine until I added the build pack.

Comment: @Osaro which buildpack did you add?

Comment: @Osaro just a thought : did you perhaps accidentally replace the buildpack? Is the python one still there?

Comment: I might have, I'm not sure. I used this line of code to add the buildpack :  ```heroku buildpacks:set  https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt  -a rivvyng```

Comment: @Osaro buildpack:set replaces the buildpack, buildpack:add adds another one

Comment: @Osaro check the dashboard of the app, there you see more